# Where does the Emperor in Dune rule from?

Tags: dune

I know that in Dune his throne is referred to as the Golden Lion Throne, and is the symbol of his house, Corrino, but I have never found any indication of where he rules from. Does the Emperor rule from Old Earth or something?

Comment: About Old Earth: it is no longer inhabited.

Comment: Yeah... I forgot about that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on which Emperor you are asking about; [Shadam Corrino IV](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Shaddam_Corrino_IV) (Emperor during Dune, who I'm guessing you are asking about) ruled from [Kaitain](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Kaitain).  He was later exiled to [Salusa Secundus](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Salusa_Secundus). (Ironic, since it was the homeworld of House Corrino.)

As far as I can see, the first reference to it is in the appendix to Dune, where it's mentioned as part of the entry on Salusa Secundus:

> SALUSA SECUNDUS: third planet of Gamma Waiping; designated Imperial Prison Planet **after removal of the Royal Court to Kaitain**. Salusa Secundus is homeworld of House Corrino, and the second stopping point in migrations of the Wandering Zensunni. Fremen tradition says they were slaves on S.S. for nine generations.

[Emphasis added]

Paul and Leto II ruled from [Arrakis](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Arrakis).

Comment: Thanks! I have been wondering about this for a while

Comment: No problem; there's a lot more data on it in the Movies/TvSeries/etc, games and the Brian Herbert books, but it's surprising how little data there is on it in the original six books.  (As I recall, I got ONE hit for Kaitain in the entire initial trilogy, and that's the appendix entry you see above.)

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR : House Corrino ruled the galaxy from Kaitain for the better part of 10,000 years. Paul Atreides & his heirs then ruled from Arrakis after capturing the throne.**

---

Generally when someone thinks of The Emperor in Dune, they are referring to [House Corrino](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/House_Corrino), which ruled the galaxy from (approximately) 88 AG until the events of [Dune](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Dune_(novel)) in 10193 AG. Although this rule was originally located on the Corrino homeworld of [Salusa Secundus](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Salusa_Secundus), it was moved early on to the Earth-like planet of [Kaitain](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Kaitain/XD). There it remained until the [Golden Lion Throne](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Lion_Throne) was usurped by [Duke Paul Atreides](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Muad%27Dib_(Paul_Atreides)), who relocated the royal court to the planet of [Arrakis](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Arrakis).

[image: 1984 Film depiction of planets]

Not much is known about the planet itself as it is barely described in any of the books. What we do know is that - despite having rings - it had a climate similar to that of [Old Earth](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Earth/XD), and that for centuries it was looked upon as the shining beacon of what civilization should be. [Video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_based_on_Dune) & [fan-art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_art) depictions of the planet have tended towards balmy weather overlooking a mountainous paradise, with the capital of [Corrinth City](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Corrinth_City) often scattered with golden buildings.

[image]

Comment: "usurped"? You sound suspiciously like a Corrino sympathizer!

Comment: @DVK : usurp (yoo-surp) [verb]; to seize and hold (a position, power, etc.) by force or without legal right. Example: None within the Landsraad can rightfully deny that Paul Atreides usurped the throne by force.

Comment: he married Irulan, so it was all quite legal, okthx? :)

Comment: @DVK : lol yes, but first he took it by force... then married Irulan after the fact to make it legal. One cannot go against the word of Fact.

Comment: He just ended ten thousand years of illegal Corrino rule. As one could put it if we believed the legends spread by *Brian Herbert* how Faykan Corrino came into power.

Comment: @Ghanima: Who? There are only 6 Dune books.

Comment: I am well aware of that. But Mr. Herbert Jr is obviously not ;) However we know (from canon) that Shaddam IV is the 81st Corrino emperor and that the Corrinos rose to power just after the Great Revolt. So while House Corrino was obviously quite succesful to hold their (de-facto) claim of the throne we have no clue how legal that claim is (I mean other than to proclaim yourself emperor and keep your house in power for ten thousand years of course ^^).

Comment: Despite the current negative connotations of the word "usurped", the word itself is not meant to be negative - it merely means that the throne was taken by force OR illegally. There's no denying that Paul took it by force.